# How to get the exit code from the source script

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I have two scripts main script and sub script and I called the subscript using source script, if the specified package is not installed then it should return exit code 1.

If I run the main script by using `bash main.sh` I am unable to get the subScriptExitCode from the main script

**main script**

```
source "sub.sh"

subScriptExitCode=$?

log "subScript ExitCode: $subScriptExitCode"

if [ $subScriptExitCode -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $subScriptExitCode
fi
```

**sub script**

```
type -p <package>

subScriptExitCode=$?

if [ $subScriptExitCode -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You may prefer to use `return` instead of `exit` inside sub.sh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a file is sourced, don't use `exit`, as this will terminate the whole execution. Instead, use `return` in sub.sh :

> return [n]
>
> Causes a function to exit with the return value specified
>   by n. If used outside  a  function,  but during execution of a script
>   by the .  (source) command, it causes the shell to stop executing that
>   script and return either n or the exit status of the last command
>   executed within the script as the exit status of the script.  If used
>   outside a function and not during execution of a script by ., the 
>   return  status  is false.

## sub.sh

```
type -p <package>

subScriptExitCode="$?"

if [ "$subScriptExitCode" -ne 0 ]; then
    return 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sourcing the sub script run it as below and check the return code

**Main.sh**

```
sh sub.sh

subScriptExitCode=$?

log "subScript ExitCode: $subScriptExitCode"

if [ $subScriptExitCode -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $subScriptExitCode
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the manual of Bash, then you read

> **`source filename [arguments]`:**
>                 Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell environment and ***return the exit status of the last command executed from `filename`***.  If `filename` does not contain ...
>
> **<sup>source: `man bash`</sup>**

These are two very important properties which are related to your problem:

1. If your `sub_script` encounters a `subScriptExitCode` which is different from zero. It will terminate the `main_script` instantaneously due to the `exit` statement.
2. The `main_script` will set `subScriptExitCode` to the exit state of the if-statement. This is zero in case `subScriuptExitCode` of `sub_script` equals `0`.

   > **`if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi`:** ... The exit status is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.
   >
   > **<sup>source: `man bash`</sup>**

A possible way to solve your problem, making use only of the properties of `source` would be:

**`sub_script`:**

```
type -p <package>
[ $? -eq 0 ]
```

Here, the test command will exit with the state `0` if `type p <package>` terminated with zero, otherwise the `test`-command will exit with state `1`. This state is then picked up in your `main_source` as `$?`. However, since `type -p` can only return `0` or `1`, you can just get rid of the `test` and reduce `sub_script` to:

```
type -p <package>
```

> **`type [-aftpP] name [name ...]`:** ... `type` returns true if all of the arguments are found, false if any are not found.
>
> **<sup>[source: `man bash`]</sup>**

Comment: `[ $? -eq 0 ]` only changes all nonzero values to 1; it serves no other useful purpose -- which is to say, `sub_script`'s exit status will be that of the last command, `type -p`, without it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just realized what you meant. I have updated the post to reflect this.